# Why can creating a singularity in the interior of a closed curve change the value of a line integral on its boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

Say I have a function $f(z) = z$ which I integrate around the circle $\gamma(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$ $(0 \leq \theta \lt 2\pi)$ on the domain $\mathbb{C}$. $f$ is analytic everywhere on and interior to the simple closed curve $\gamma$, therefore I can conclude by the Cauchy-Goursat theorem that $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}f(z)\: dz = 0$.

Now say I remove the origin from the domain, so I re-define the domain to be $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$. $\gamma$ is no longer a simple closed curve as it contains a singularity at $0$. Cauchy-Goursat no longer applies, but if I compute the integral this time by hand I still get $0$.

Is it just a technicality that Cauchy-Goursat doesn't apply in this case? What is an example of a situation where the integral is $0$ by Cauchy-Goursat, then I create some singularity in the interior of the closed curve which causes the integral to no longer be $0$? I am quite confused by the concept that changing the interior of a curve would cause a line integral on the boundary of that curve to be different.

Comment: There are no singularities on the unit circle, whether you choose to look at the origin or not. What matters is how the function you are integrating behaves in the region enclosed. For example, the integral of $1/z$ over the unit circle is not zero, and it will never change, no matter what you do to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Goursat (CG) theorem in its simplest form refers to a closed curve $\gamma$ lying in a *simply connected* domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ on which $f$ is analytic. Then $\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=0$.

If $\Omega={\mathbb C}$ then $\Omega$ is simply connected, and you can conclude that $\int_\gamma z\>dz=0$.

If, however, $\Omega:={\mathbb C}\setminus \{0\}$, then $\Omega$ is *not* simply connected, and the CG theorem *does not apply*. But you can prove $\int_\gamma z\>dz=0$ by other means, e.g., by explicitly computing the integral, or noting that $z\mapsto z$ is in fact analytic in the larger domain $\tilde\Omega={\mathbb C}$, on which the CG theorem may be applied.